# Limit of an integral of gradient

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Let $U$ be an open connected set with smooth boundary in $\mathbb{R}^{d}$ and $U_{n} = \{x \in U: d(x, \partial U) > 1/n\}$. Let $f_{n} \in C_{c}^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^{d})$ such that $f_{n}(x) = 1$ on $U_{n}$ and $0$ outside $U$ (we can find such an $f_{n}$ by Urysohn's Lemma). Is there a way to rigorously justify that $$\int_{\mathbb{R}^{d}}|\nabla f_{n}|\, dx \rightarrow m(\partial U)$$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$? Here $m$ denotes $d - 1$ dimensional Lebesgue measure.

Comment: Do you mean $n-1$ dimensional Hausdorff measure?

Comment: @John: It is since $d-1$ since he is working on $\mathbb{R}^d$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is actually not true if you choose $f_n$ in an arbitrary way. For example, let $d=1$ and $U = (-1,1)$. Then consider $f=f_n$ to be smooth and of compact support in $(-1,1)$ such that

- $f(x) = f(-x)$,
- $f(x) = 1 \text{ for }|x|\leq 1-1/n$,
- $f(1-1/2n) = 2$,
- $f$ is increasing in $(1-1/n, 1-1/2n)$ and
- $f$ is decreasing in $(1-1/2n, 1)$.

Then

$$\int_{-1}^1 |f'| dx = 2\int_0^1 |f'| dx = 2\bigg( \int_{1-1/n}^{1-1/2n} f'(x)dx - \int_{1-1/2n}^{1} f'(x)dx\bigg)$$

$$=2\big( f(1-1/2n) -f(1-1/n) - f(1) + f(1-1/2n)\big) = 2 (2-1 -0 + 2) = 6$$
$$\neq 2 = \mathscr H^0 (\partial U)\ .$$

After some thought, one can only at best show:

**Theorem** We have 
$$\liminf_{n\to \infty} \int_U |\nabla f_n | dx \geq \mathscr H^{d-1}(\partial U)\ .$$

To prove this theorem, first we break $\partial U$ into small portions (called $M$) so that we assume there is a $d-1$ open submanifold $M$ in $\mathbb R^d$ and there is a open set $W$ in $\mathbb R^d$ which admits a parametrization of the normal bundle of $M$.

That is, $M$ is given by a smooth embedding $F:D\to \mathbb R^d$, $ D \subset \mathbb R^{d-1}$, then locally there is a parametrization of $W$ given by $\tilde F : D \times (-\epsilon, \epsilon)\to W \subset \mathbb R^d$,

$$\tilde F(y^1, \cdots, y^{d-1}, t) = F(y^1, \cdots, y^{d-1}) +t v (y^1, \cdots, y^{d-1}),$$

where $v$ is the normal vector of $M$. Let $f_n$ be a smooth function on $W$, such that

$$f(y, t) = 0 \text{ when }t\leq 0 \text{ and } f(y, t) = 1\ \text{when }t\geq 1/n\ .$$

Let $g_{ij}$ be the metric on $M$, then on $W$ we have the metric $\tilde g_{ij}$ given by

$$\tilde g_{ij} = g_{ij}+ t^2 \langle v_i, v_j\rangle \ \text{ for }i, j=1, \cdots ,d-1\ , \tilde g_{tj} = 0, \ \tilde g_{tt} = 1\ .$$

With respect to this parametrization, locally we have

$$\int_W |\nabla f_n| dx = \int_{-\epsilon}^\epsilon \int_D |\nabla f_n| dV, $$

where

$$dV = \sqrt{\det(\tilde g_{ij})} dy^1\cdots dy^{n-1}dt \ .$$

On the other hand, decomposes $\nabla f$ into normal and tangential component (corresponds to where $t$ is fixed) $\nabla f = \partial _t + \nabla^\perp f$, then

$$|\nabla f|^2 = |\partial_t f|^2  + |\nabla^\perp f|^2\Rightarrow |\nabla f|\geq |\partial_t  f|\ . $$

$$\Rightarrow \int_W |\nabla f| dx \geq \int_W |\partial_t f| dx \geq  \int_W \partial_t f dx $$

So the theorem follows from the

**Claim** We have

$$\lim_{n\to \infty} \int_W \partial_t f dx \geq \mathscr H^{d-1}(\partial U)\ .$$

First we have the equality

$$\partial _t f\sqrt{ \det(\tilde g_{ij})} = \partial_t \big(f  \sqrt{ \det(\tilde g_{ij})} \big) - \frac{t}{2} f \sqrt{\det (\tilde g_{ij})} |A|_t^2, $$

where $|A|^2_t$ is the norm of the second fundamental form with respect to the metric $\tilde g_{ij}$ at time $t$. Then using fundamental theorem of calculus,

$$\int_W \partial_t f dx = \int_D \int_{-\epsilon}^\epsilon \partial _t \sqrt{\det (\tilde g_{ij})} dydt = \int_D dV_t - \frac{t}{2} \int_W f |A|^2_t dx$$

$$= \mathscr H^{d-1} (M_t) - \frac{1}{2} \int_W f t|A|^2_t dx \to \mathscr H^{d-1}(M)$$

as $n\to \infty$.

(Well, this is a bit messy, please feel free to ask if you do not understand the notations)

**Remark** So from the proof we see that in order that the statement claimed by the OP is true, we need a good approximation sequence $f_n$ such that they are

- "decreasing along the normal direction" (So that $\partial _t f = |\partial _t f|$), and
- Has "small tangential gradient" $\nabla^\perp f$.

I guess such a sequence of functions can be constructed, for example for modifying the distance function to $\partial U$. But in general it is not clear what conditions on $f_n$ would guaranteed that the limits exists.